# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAndroidId on channel samples.flutter.dev/battery)

Tags: flutter, background-service, flutter-workmanager

I trying to call native methods in background service but it throws me an exception.

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAndroidId on channel samples.flutter.dev/battery)

but it working fine while I try to run this on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

create a flutter package for all of your native methods and use it as a dependency on  your flutter project and call the methods in the background service. make sure your flutter engine must me initialized for background service.

**ref:**
How to create flutter package : https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages